# Regex on Splitting String

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to split the following string into proper output using regex. Answers do not have to be in perl but in general regex is fine:

Username is required.
Multi-string name is optional
Followed by Uselessword is there but should be be parsed
Followed by an optional number
Following by an IP in brackets < > (Required)

String = `username optional multistring name uselessword 45 <100.100.100.100>`

Output should be:

```
Match 1 = username
Match 2 = optional multistring name
Match 3 = 45
Match 4 = 100.100.100.100
```

Comment: Just curious: what were you trying?  (_I am trying to split the following string into proper output using regex_)

Comment: `(?<username>\w+)\s(?<dummy>.+)\s\w+\s(?<number>\d+)\s<(?<ip>.*)>`. But since perl doesn't support named captures: `(\w+)\s(.+)\s\w+\s(\d+)\s<(.*)>`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Actually, as of 5.10, [Perl *does* support named captures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences).

Answer (score 0):

This sort of things are easier to handle using multiple regex. Here is an example:

```
my @arr = (
'username optional multistring name uselessword 45 <100.100.100.100>',
'username 45 <100.100.100.100>'
);

for(@arr){
    ## you can use anchor ^ $ here
    if(/(\S+) (.+?) (\d+) <(.+?)>/){
        print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n";
    }

    ## you can use anchor ^ $ here
    elsif(/(\S+) (\d+) <(.+?)>/){
        print "$1\n$2\n\n$3\n";
    }
    print "==========\n";
}
```

First `if` block is looking for four groups from the input. And the second block is looking for three groups.

If you need, you can use `[ ]+` to handle multiple spaces between the groups.

Also, if you need, you can adjust the optional group `(.+?)` according to your preferred characters(usually through the character class `[bla]`).